# SQL PIVOT with two result sets - reordering result columns by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I've created a stored procedure to pull data from a table and display summarised information based on the number of occurrences in a day. The columns are dynamic.

What's the best way to order the columns by date descending?

The query:

```
--Declare Query
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Declare COUNT variables
DECLARE @ColumnNameCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnNameAgregateCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Declare SUM variables
DECLARE @ColumnNameSUM AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnNameAgregateSUM AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct COUNT values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnNameCOUNT= ISNULL(@ColumnNameCOUNT + ',','') + QUOTENAME([ReportDate])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ReportDate] FROM [tbBackordersArchive]) AS BackorderDates

--Get summed COUNT values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnNameAgregateCOUNT = COALESCE(@ColumnNameAgregateCOUNT + ', SUM(','Sum(')+  QUOTENAME([ReportDate]) + ') as '+ QUOTENAME([ReportDate])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ReportDate] FROM [tbBackordersArchive]) AS BackorderDates

--Get distinct SUM values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnNameSUM= ISNULL(@ColumnNameSUM + ',','') + QUOTENAME([ReportDate])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ReportDate] FROM [tbBackordersArchive]) AS BackorderDates

--Get summed SUM values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnNameAgregateSUM = COALESCE(@ColumnNameAgregateSUM + ', SUM(','Sum(')+  QUOTENAME([ReportDate]) + ') as '+ QUOTENAME([ReportDate])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ReportDate] FROM [tbBackordersArchive]) AS BackorderDates

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ' + @ColumnNameAgregateCOUNT + '
    FROM [tbBackordersArchive]
    PIVOT(COUNT(OrderedQuantity)
          FOR [ReportDate] IN (' + @ColumnNameCOUNT + ')) AS PVTTable WHERE [Warehouse] = ''01''

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ' + @ColumnNameAgregateSUM + '
    FROM [tbBackordersArchive]
    PIVOT(SUM(OrderedQuantity)
          FOR [ReportDate] IN (' + @ColumnNameSUM + ')) AS PVTTable WHERE [Warehouse] = ''01'''

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbBackordersArchive](
[ReportDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[Warehouse] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
[PartNumber] [nvarchar](26) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](37) NULL,
[PDCStock] [float] NULL,
[Account] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[AccountName] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
[CreditHold] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
[CustomerRef] [nvarchar](22) NULL,
[WIP] [int] NULL,
[DateEdit] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
[OrderedQuantity] [float] NULL,
[CumulativeQuantity] [float] NULL,
[OrderType] [nvarchar](3) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Order by the date when you are setting the variables that contain the new pivot column names.

Comment: Thanks HEAPS Rabbit !!!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rabbit suggested here is the resolved code (please see the ORDER BY in @ColumnNameAgregateSUM and @ColumnNameAgregateCOUNT:

```
--Declare Query
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Declare COUNT variables
DECLARE @ColumnNameCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnNameAgregateCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Declare SUM variables
DECLARE @ColumnNameSUM AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnNameAgregateSUM AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct COUNT values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnNameCOUNT= ISNULL(@ColumnNameCOUNT + ',','') + QUOTENAME([ReportDate])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ReportDate] FROM [tbBackordersArchive]) AS BackorderDates

--Get summed COUNT values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnNameAgregateCOUNT = COALESCE(@ColumnNameAgregateCOUNT + ', SUM(','Sum(')+  QUOTENAME([ReportDate]) + ') as '+ QUOTENAME([ReportDate])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ReportDate] FROM [tbBackordersArchive]) AS BackorderDates ORDER BY [ReportDate] DESC

--Get distinct SUM values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnNameSUM= ISNULL(@ColumnNameSUM + ',','') + QUOTENAME([ReportDate])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ReportDate] FROM [tbBackordersArchive]) AS BackorderDates

--Get summed SUM values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnNameAgregateSUM = COALESCE(@ColumnNameAgregateSUM + ', SUM(','Sum(')+  QUOTENAME([ReportDate]) + ') as '+ QUOTENAME([ReportDate])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [ReportDate] FROM [tbBackordersArchive]) AS BackorderDates ORDER BY [ReportDate] DESC

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT ' + @ColumnNameAgregateCOUNT + '
    FROM [tbBackordersArchive]
    PIVOT(COUNT(OrderedQuantity)
          FOR [ReportDate] IN (' + @ColumnNameCOUNT + ')) AS PVTTable WHERE [Warehouse] = ''01''

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ' + @ColumnNameAgregateSUM + '
    FROM [tbBackordersArchive]
    PIVOT(SUM(OrderedQuantity)
          FOR [ReportDate] IN (' + @ColumnNameSUM + ')) AS PVTTable WHERE [Warehouse] = ''01'''

--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```